# jQuery namespace does not bubble which custom event

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1" >
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
</div>

<a class="btn1">customClick.btn1</a>
<a class="btn2">customClick.btn2</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
 jQuery('div.child1')
    .bind('customClick.btn1', function () {
        alert('child1 reacted to customClick.btn1');
    });


 jQuery('div.child2')
    .bind('customClick.btn2', function () {
        alert('child2 reacted to customClick.btn2');
    });

 jQuery('div.parent')
    .bind('customClick.btn1', function (e) {
      alert('parent reacted to customClick.btn1');
    })
    .bind('customClick.btn2', function (e) {
       alert('parent reacted to customClick.btn2');
    });

jQuery('a.btn1')
    .click(function(){
        jQuery('div.child1').trigger('customClick.btn1');
    });

jQuery('a.btn2')
    .click(function(){
        jQuery('div.child2').trigger('customClick.btn2');
    });
```

When I click `a.btn1`, as expected, the `customClick.btn1` event is handled by `div.child1` and not `div.child2`. What is not expected is that the `customClick` event bubbles and triggers the handlers on `div.parent` for both `customClick.btn1` and `customClick.btn2`. Is this right? Is there any way to have custom events bubble with their namespace? In other words, when `customClick.btn1` is triggered, not all parent handlers for `customClick` are handled, just ones that handle `customClick.btn1`.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `#content` from your selectors as there isn't an element with that id in your example. Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/HUALM/1/

Comment: sorry, #content doesnt even need to be there. my bad

Comment: fyi i removed #content from the selector strings

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs, it looks like when you're doing namespacing, the part *before* the `.` is the event type. So that is the event that is being triggered.

As such, the `.parent` element has 2 `customClick` event types bound to it. That is why they both fire.

**From the docs:** http://api.jquery.com/bind/

> If the eventType string contains a period (.) character, then the event is namespaced. The period character separates the event from its namespace. For example, in the call .bind('click.name', handler), the string click is the event type, and the string name is the namespace. Namespacing allows us to unbind or trigger some events of a type without affecting others.

It would seem to be a reasonable expectation that the namespace would be considered when the event bubbles, but apparently not.

You could instead check the `e.target.className` to see which element was triggered. There must also be a way to get the namespacing that you could test from the event object.

---

**EDIT:**

Looks like you could test for the namespace of the event object like this:

```
if(e.handleObj.namespace === 'btn1')
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @Nick Craver demonstrated in the comment below, the namespace *is* considered in bubbling when the namespaced events are *not* bound to the children. As such (one way or the other) it seems like a bug.

Either way, you should still be able to test for the namespace as noted above since the property does seem to be present in the Event object in both cases.

Comment: This complicates it a bit though: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bNbpN/ if the `.child1` and `.child2` *aren't* bound, it does bubble correctly, with a namespace, it's the first bound handler that doesn't pass it on, where native bubbling does, I'm not sure of the *intended* behavior here, but seems like a bug.

Comment: @Nick - Well, that *is* strange. It does seem to me that the expected behavior would be to have the namespace considered when bubbling. After all, if one took the time to give a namespace to the events on `.parent` as well as the descendants, it would seem a reasonable expectation that a matched namespace would be desired in event handling, even when bubbling. I'd agree that it seems like a bug.

Comment: Testing for the namespace does not actually help you. If you click a.btn1, div.parent will handle both 'customClick.btn1' and 'customClick.btn2' with their respective namespaces. Using firebug, you can see that both handlers are entered with the namespace they are supposed to handle and the target property for both is div.child1. So big question is why is the div.child1 triggerring 'customClick.btn2' in this case. Also I am going to post  a temporary solution that gets dont what I am trying to do. Hopefully, one beautiful day, I will return to the namespaced event syntax.

Comment: @Adrian - Ok, I see what you mean. Both events are bubbling, so each has its own namespace that is tested, and then firing.

Comment: This is still a bug in 1.7.2.

Comment: Testing the namespace does not seem to work, as it reports the namespace of what the event was bound to, and not the namespace of what was triggered. For example, triggering 'update.global' triggers an 'update' event for an element bound to 'update.game', and e.handleObj.namespace is reported as 'game'.  ... Ah, I see that's what Adrian said above. I will try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1" >
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
</div>

<a class="btn1">customClick.btn1</a>
<a class="btn2">customClick.btn2</a>
```

jQuery

```
 jQuery('div.child1')
    .bind('customClick', function (e) {
        if(e.namespace == 'btn1'){
          console.log('child1 reacted to customClick.btn1');
        }
    });


 jQuery('div.child2')
    .bind('customClick', function (e) {
       if(e.namespace == 'btn2'){
          console.log('child2 reacted to customClick.btn2');
       }
    });

 jQuery('div.parent')
    .bind('customClick', function (e) {
      if(e.namespace == 'btn1'){
          console.log('parent reacted to customClick.btn1');
      }
      if(e.namespace == 'btn2'){
          console.log('parent reacted to customClick.btn2');
      }
    })


jQuery('a.btn1')
    .click(function(){
        jQuery('div.child1').trigger({type:'customClick',namespace:'btn1'});
    });

jQuery('a.btn2')
    .click(function(){
        jQuery('div.child2').trigger({type:'customClick',namespace:'btn2'});
    });
```

While this works, I would love to do it the way I was doing it before. I opened up a ticket with jQuery. Ticket #6913  Thanks Nick Craver and patrick dw for helping confirm the issue.

Comment: I was just about to ask if you were going to file a bug report. Definitely needs a fix.